# Increase IMAP chunk size in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, imap

I cannot find any possible way of increasing the buffer size for fetching mails in Rails using either net/imap or the mail gem from mikel at github.

Problem:
I want to fetch mails everytime a user logs in and that's too slow at the moment. It takes about 20sec to fetch 40 mails which are having no more then 5MB in total. I'm using gmail at the moment for testing, so that shouldn't be the bottleneck either. I don't want to have a local copy of all mails, so storing them is not a solution too.

So at the moment it seems to me that it's a problem of small chunks of 16KB which is default of IMAP and that it should be much faster when you could change the size of chunks.

I have the following method for fetching the mails:

```
def fetch_headers
  imap = Net::IMAP.new('imap.googlemail.com', ssl: true)
  begin
    imap.authenticate('PLAIN', 'mail@...', 'password')
  rescue Net::IMAP::Exception => err
    raise Error, err.message
  end
  assessment_memos = []
  begin
    imap.select('INBOX')
    imap.search('ALL').each do |msg_id|
      msg = imap.fetch(msg_id, 'BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (Date From Subject)]')
      header_hash = to_hash_helper msg[0].attr['BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (Date From Subject)]']
      assessment_memos.push(header_hash)
    end
  ensure
    imap.logout
    imap.disconnect
  end
  assessment_memos
end
```

Comment: IMAP doesn't have a default chunk size. The simplest ways to fetch mail in IMAP don't use chunking at all, in fact. The usual problem is that the client fetches one message at a time, so most time is spent in a back-and-forth between client and server. The client can instead request all the messages it wants and get a streaming download, drastically faster. Well, faster until you come across a ten-million-message gmail account. Those do exist. Having written all this, I think I'll vote to close the question since it's lacking in detail. There's no code to show what you're doing.

Comment: Hi arnt, thanks for your reply. I've added the code for fetching the mails. So all in all, I'm just calling the fetch method from imap. Do you know how to enable fetching them all by one?

Comment: [Fetch retrieves a set of messages](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/net/imap/rdoc/Net/IMAP.html#method-i-fetch), you're using search.each to make n sets of 1 message each, then you fetch each of the 1-message sets, maximising both network delay and server work.

Comment: you're right. Thanks!